# How to calculate eigenvalues?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given is differential equation: $2y''+5y'-3y=0$
Write this equations as 1. order system and calculate eigenvalues of the matrix of this differential equation.

My idea:

$z_{1}=y$

$z_{2}=y'$

$\frac{d}{dx}\begin{pmatrix} z_{1} \\ z_{2}  \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} z_{2} \\ \frac{3}{2}z_{1}-\frac{5}{2}z_{2}   \end{pmatrix}  $

But how do I get matrix to calculate eigenvalues?

Answer (score 3):

You have done. Your system can be written as:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\frac{3}{2}&\frac{-5}{2}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so you have the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\begin{pmatrix} z_{1} \\ z_{2}  \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} z_{2} \\ \frac{3}{2}z_{1}-\frac{5}{2}z_{2}   \end{pmatrix}$$

You're close, simply rewrite:
$$\begin{pmatrix} z_{2} \\ \frac{3}{2}z_{1}-\frac{5}{2}z_{2}   \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 0z_1+ 1z_{2} \\ \frac{3}{2}z_{1}-\frac{5}{2}z_{2}   \end{pmatrix}
=\color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1  \\ \frac{3}{2} & -\frac{5}{2}  \end{pmatrix}}
\begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2  \end{pmatrix}$$
Now you want to diagonalize the blue matrix.

Can you calculate its eigenvalues? You should find $-3$ and $\tfrac{1}{2}$.